# Python list manipulation based on indexing

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

The first list consists of all the titles of various publications where as the second list consists of all the author names.

```
list B = ['Moe Terry M 2005 ', 'March James G and Johan P Olsen 2006 ', 'Kitschelt Herbert 2000 ', 'Bates Robert H 1981 ' , .......]

list A = ['"Linkages between Citizens and Politicians in Democratic Polities,"', '"Winners Take All: The Politics of Partial Reform in Postcommunist \n\nTransitions,"', '"Inequality, Social Insurance, and \n\nRedistribution."', '"Majoritarian Electoral Systems and \nConsumer Power: Price-Level Evidence from the OECD Countries."']
```

I am running scholar.py as a bash command. The syntax goes like this

```
scholar = "python scholar.py -c 1 --author " + str(name) + "--phrase  " + str(title)
```

Now, what I am trying to do is get each title and author in order so that I can use them with scholar.
But I am not able to figure out how can I get the first author name with first title .

I would have used indexing if the lists were small.

Comment: How big are the lists? Could you just zip the two lists together assuming the lists are order such that each item correspond to the other ?

Comment: The list is very big ..  and yes the lists are in order such that each item correspond to the other

Comment: I was not aware of the zip function in Python.. But yes,.  that solves the problem... Thank you so much

Comment: @M.D how much time did you spend in looking for an answer online and trying the suggestions before posting this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this is what you are looking for?

```
list B = ['Moe Terry M 2005 ', 'March James G and Johan P Olsen 2006 ', 'Kitschelt Herbert 2000 ', 'Bates Robert H 1981 ' , .......]

list A = ['"Linkages between Citizens and Politicians in Democratic Polities,"', '"Winners Take All: The Politics of Partial Reform in Postcommunist \n\nTransitions,"', '"Inequality, Social Insurance, and \n\nRedistribution."', '"Majoritarian Electoral Systems and \nConsumer Power: Price-Level Evidence from the OECD Countries."']

for i,j in zip(B,A):
     print i, j #python 2.x
     print(i , j) #python3.x
```